# Merge two xml files without duplicates

Tags: powershell

I need write script in powershell merge two files into one without duplicates.
Maybe are some written script for it?

I Have two XML files that store translations of system objects: 1.xml and 2.xml.
I need script to merges  files into one and saves them in a separate -
3.xml. In 3.xml file cannot be repeated.

XML1.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<group id="body">
  <trans-unit id="Table 3993789018 - Field 269761521 - Property 2879900210" size-unit="char" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>State</source>
    <target state="translated">busena</target>
    <note from="Developer" annotates="general" priority="2"></note>
    <note from="Xliff Generator" annotates="general" priority="3">Table AAD Application - Field State - Property Caption</note>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="Table 3993789018 - Field 269761521 - Property 62802879" size-unit="char" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Enabled,Disabled</source>
    <target state="translated">ijungta,isjungta</target>
    <note from="Developer" annotates="general" priority="2"></note>
    <note from="Xliff Generator" annotates="general" priority="3">Table AAD Application - Field State - Property OptionCaption</note>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="Table 3993789018 - Property 2879900210" size-unit="char" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>AAD Application</source>
    <target state="translated">AAD programa</target>
    <note from="Developer" annotates="general" priority="2"></note>
    <note from="Xliff Generator" annotates="general" priority="3">Table AAD Application - Property Caption</note>
  </trans-unit>
</group>
```

XML2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<group id="body">
  <trans-unit id="Table 3993789018 - Field 1256520770 - Property 2879900210" size-unit="char" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>App Name</source>
    <target state="translated">Programos pavadinimas</target>
    <note from="Developer" annotates="general" priority="2"></note>
    <note from="Xliff Generator" annotates="general" priority="3">Table AAD Application - Field App Name - Property Caption</note>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="Table 3993789018 - Field 269761521 - Property 2879900210" size-unit="char" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>State</source>
    <target state="translated">busena</target>
    <note from="Developer" annotates="general" priority="2"></note>
    <note from="Xliff Generator" annotates="general" priority="3">Table AAD Application - Field State - Property Caption</note>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="Table 3993789018 - Field 269761521 - Property 62802879" size-unit="char" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Enabled,Disabled</source>
    <target state="translated">ijungta, isjungta</target>
    <note from="Developer" annotates="general" priority="2"></note>
    <note from="Xliff Generator" annotates="general" priority="3">Table AAD Application - Field State - Property OptionCaption</note>
  </trans-unit>
</group>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried, what worked and what didn't work, so we can help you with **your** code.

Comment: @Theo I think I can use copy/b *.xml merged.xml, but if I need remove duplicates, I need use IF statement by  <source>AAD Application</source> eq <source>AAD Application</source> but I dont know how.

Comment: Use Simon's great guide here to get started and then post a question when you get stuck.  https://blog.simonw.se/use-powershell-to-merge-xml/